# How to start a program Automatically from the main method

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
def main():
    # This code reads in data.txt and loads it into an array
    # Array will be used to add friends, remove and list
    # when we quit, we'll overwrite original friends.txt with
    # contents 

    print"Welcome to the program"

    print "Enter the correct number"
    print "Hockey fan 1, basketball fan 2, cricket fan 3"
    choice = input("Select an option")

    while choice!=3:
        if choice==1:
            addString = raw_input("Who is your favorite player??")
            print "I love Kessel"
        elif choice==2:
            remInt = raw_input("Do you think that the Cavaliers will continue ther loosing ways?")
            print "I think they can beat the Clippers"
        else:
             "You must choose a Number (1,2 or 3)"
    print "Cricket is a great sport"
    choice = input("Select an option")



    inFile = open('data.txt','r')
    listNumbers = []
    for numbers in inFile:
        listNumbers.append(numbers)
        print numbers
    inFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() # will call the 'main' function only when you execute this from the command line.
```

Comment: It should be noted that the question doesn't make sense, because it has been corrected by some "smart" people.  Sheesh.  *Question* and *Answer*.

Answer (score 12):

Add:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To your script (indented all the way to the left; not as part of the `main()` function).

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to the end of the file

Comment: I tried and the program wont run it shows a syntax error

Comment: Can you please add it to the end of my code and run it and see if it will work for you

Comment: I don't have a python interpreter at hand. What's the error message?

Comment: @liam: your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should try the following

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Once that is done, you should call your program as follows from the command line (assuming you are on Linux/Mac)

```
python <your_prog>
```

Also it will be helpful if you give the exact error that you are getting.
Also make sure that all the indentation is correct.